# TypeScript how to type narrow a generic with typeof?

Tags: typescript, generics, react-hooks, type-narrowing

I'm experimenting with writing a custom React hook that stores state in the URL.  As part of that I set the default type of the state to be `string` (since the URL is a big string) and I provide a `customValueConverters` parameter which allows people to go from their custom type to a string and back again.

The `defaultValue` has the same type as the type of the state and so I was hoping to use that to type narrow from `TState` to `string` and use the `stringValueConverters` in that case:

```
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

export function useSearchParamsState<TState = string>(
    searchParamName: string,
    defaultValue: TState,
    customValueConverters?: ValueConverters<TState>
): readonly [
    searchParamsState: TState,
    setSearchParamsState: (newState: TState) => void
] {
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

    let valueConverters = customValueConverters;

    if (!customValueConverters && typeof defaultValue === "string")
        valueConverters = stringValueConverters;

    const acquiredSearchParam = searchParams.get(searchParamName);
    const searchParamsState = acquiredSearchParam
        ? valueConverters.parse(acquiredSearchParam)
        : defaultValue;

    const setSearchParamsState = (newState: TState) => {
        const next = Object.assign(
            {},
            [...searchParams.entries()].reduce(
                (o, [key, value]) => ({ ...o, [key]: value }),
                {}
            ),
            { [searchParamName]: valueConverters.stringify(newState) }
        );
        setSearchParams(next);
    };
    return [searchParamsState, setSearchParamsState];
}

interface ValueConverters<TState> {
    parse: (state: string) => TState;
    stringify: (state: TState) => string;
}

const stringValueConverters: ValueConverters<string> = {
    parse: (state: string) => state,
    stringify: (state: string) => state,
};
```

However this errors out with `Type 'ValueConverters<string>' is not assignable to type 'ValueConverters<TState>'.`. This surprises me as I would hope TypeScript would detect the type narrowing on `defaultValue` and allow this.  It doesn't...

Comment: In addition to addressing types, there are some runtime issues with the approach you've shown. Are you open to receiving an answer in the form of a refactor, like this? https://tsplay.dev/NlEBRm If so, I can write that up for you, including a bit more explanation of the changes in addition to the comments that are already there in the playground.

Comment: Go for it! I'd be intrigued

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than simply addressing the question you asked, I've created a refactor / alternative implementation because [you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73352371/typescript-how-to-type-narrow-a-generic-with-typeof?noredirect=1#comment129543602_73352371) that you were interested.

For context — because you're using the `useSearchParams` hook — here are its associated types from its [documentation page](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params#usesearchparams):

> ```ts
> declare function useSearchParams(
>   defaultInit?: URLSearchParamsInit
> ): [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams];
>
> type ParamKeyValuePair = [string, string];
>
> type URLSearchParamsInit =
>   | string
>   | ParamKeyValuePair[]
>   | Record<string, string | string[]>
>   | URLSearchParams;
>
> type SetURLSearchParams = (
>   nextInit?: URLSearchParamsInit,
>   navigateOpts?: : { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
> ) => void;
> ```

One of the core features of [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) that distinguishes it from an object or even a `Map` is that it allows for repeated/duplicate keys. In the code you've shown, any potential serial values associated with the same key are collapsed (overwritten by the last in the series):

```js
[...searchParams.entries()].reduce(
  (o, [key, value]) => ({...o, [key]: value}),
  {}
)
```

Additionally, it might also be nice to allow for specifying the additional options argument to the `SetURLSearchParams` function returned by `useSearchParams`:

```ts
navigateOpts?: : { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
```

The implementation below acknowledges the above, and it also uses a series of [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to provide specialized return types, inferred from each combination of input options (the comments in the usage section of the code describe this more).

If you have any follow up questions, feel free to post a comment in reply.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBlNBDKBjACwAVdsQUBfOAMyghDgHIoc8YBaOpGNKdgE3qMA3AChRMAJ5g0cALLZJAIzQAeACoA+OAF446uAB84SAHb801YKbT8xUmXACipmFEmqA0mkkAaOABq2AA2SGjaegDa3n6BIWEAumKi1GZswBCmcMAWrsBScBqaABQAbvFoAFz6AJTVBgiicHAsMEhQWeWhaGIU4g6yGG7WAObqUNimKNTQILwoRbqITXBguOjVZRXVKMOmIzW62upizbtQo8DUkptdYfWHOtrno73JA3AkUOj8WLiEXzIWBgPCgiz0xRWNgAHjAgt16r4odhSsARtgeAB5MAwDJTAD81UBc1BCwASmg2h11NI1AMINQTOg-vhiKRyJpIgBGBKcnlIx7aUoQHLvWlwFkA9koIYYtTqfzY3GZEJLaghdARFo4QSmYKSOCRFZ3KpwJV41VoWFocwoOBuMJwfHyRQqRaIlboEG8InrWyStkTEDA0FFJFJcSpUzpTJMzA4VnEmUwOWFLTFCA4vEoaoIOCmMiml77YRwCzqpDBGD1UtUABkEr2YwmUxmUDm3yKdQlCalQeTcqKYijMayqHj-0DZAHPDTJUzyqmufzhZ2Tbg9cbF3240m01m8y71QDSdlPA0-gd4WHaUXcZP0rPsgzWcyOcQK7ma+3I1L5ewlbVnAxa-hu3YPv2T6qCBmg3tGd7jhB05PnAL6Lu+eYFl+wHrhQ4G9lO5BQSBl5QGEsEpLeeL3gRp4prORRodmmwrA2mGrjhP5-pYAFVoS+i1qxny4LiISqEMP67q2B6dlomiiDUhyNM0eBvvACBYWg-hrN8sh6DkNq4lI0FNpo-ggVcBr6bkRkeDBVB6Au2anHAqlTPAkQ6dO5mUkmCRLIhtHSsUNQucElJwCa9RGJxowxWY5bWLYSxeeQAB0IyUsUmmHPizoJZYSV2CsVyofSjImroOh6IwIGMIclV6Dp6BbN0oUrGgwToNkjLFOVcBOW+aX-oBcAAITVUwBVWDY-D1ZFFRLINUzDTxgHJCpanAZSoK+rpvxBUGIa8OCqEmv4aWXSwuyCsszSbe5cCGRcaDvi4bh2U25mmZE-lRBGKzNG2qFubsT2uO4A2MqlKBpc9wCvSFSmA-dpXFM9kiRAADP5E16Dl4PDK9aVgKgBDoxDkjtfdG7iDToPwKUSzFBZ1xwNgdoSaMUn7u2h5aJEtVNpZjAJDUrVhNT93w8TpMoOTkSaf4pRiy5Zy+cFMsoBdV2vTAUsUBt2pUlkkTndt3pQP5HOuWpvTiKIAD0jtwAAqig2CZZU4jO3AAByEDs1AIw5qIgWTnRcohaWjsAFTOFAdBQHAABMACsacACyiAAfnn+cF4XRc53AseOz7LsBwNr5LmHzKHch9FoMUCB4TH8dOIn0CpwA7AAbAAnCjNMj6PzR56X5dO5XgcjVW2ooIBdrWKsEAoCgwBKPqJjmIVs0LQiogM4axpcv4vvH6UXLVAoyhqDBnpn3AF9bSg1-CftSHBjtJ0P39NER0fE3FumlqiMAIJ1YIEBGBtwrnAAAktGUI-A4rYDLGtee10l7ZCyGgxKph8iyCikfLaRpmilBTufF2l8U7flGJ6Shz9qGv1oR-H4X9jpgj-gFeugDILAI0hxcBkDoH+DnkBRgAB3aAwQ5qwOnvoCB9pxQMntEo8RB9HQgFQPAEAGJCBqNkK0doWQPgMgUTAJRYA6CogsPwe0LYUAMnbDQKYqFu4qHZrFfYNQ0qKNkG4PcbYGDUDcbgG0jB4DWIgLY2wSJfZOK8QAIlMEgEAKgoBJOyHaUwEBGYhByHACBLBvbh0TEAqOgjsLCOCFAxgYiMFARTm3Z+Hcu7JxTv3IeY8em9L6fdYu+dJ5wLkMAdecUkms0kFkwJ0kXGhNKbw8p-DKnImqRA2poiVjNVNCzNwdCfFHE4mlcK+xLFwG0IwuOCck690HisQZjynnPOGfI32ozxn7DgEknZMzHHBNcYsicyzG6rOaKApgGy6lIjOMLa4mwlAQAgMEaoiLkU4FMLdRg9TWk3O7p0+549nnEsGa89qCiq4aKwVWZeWRIDjK3gaaaRVNFVBIY9MhkUADMVDbaPVKFym+ro1BovCpMeSZweVML5WDFAgq2H+gbt-S2qhRUYvkv-MpfZQU8Bbms00NToXbL9Jsc4ByDhHPOCcm0IxzmXJhd4kYlkEVIpRXANVkwsX1NEG8l2iC8DINQegismDXrYJXngvehDWXe2Ppy0omdeWX0zqi11GLPSJulcfFAKaFUHT4UCH+YIPWmA1Tw4F2qiICP1WAqFWzmjiOqFeB1OzTX7MdbdK1pzbUEAuanB1UyXXItTeiz1RzsVIlgUAA)

```ts
import {useSearchParams} from 'react-router-dom';

type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;
type Entry<Key, Value> = [Key, Value];

function identity <T>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}

type StringTransformers<T> = {
  parse: (value: string) => T;
  stringify: (value: T) => string;
};

type ParsedSearchParamSetter<T> = (
  nextValue: T,
  navigateOptions?: Parameters<ReturnType<typeof useSearchParams>[1]>[1],
) => void;

type SearchParamsState<T, Optional = false> = readonly [
  value: Optional extends true ? Maybe<T> : T,
  setter: ParsedSearchParamSetter<T>,
];

function useSearchParamsState <T>(options: { name: string; default: T; } & StringTransformers<T>): SearchParamsState<T>;
function useSearchParamsState <T>(options: { name: string } & StringTransformers<T>): SearchParamsState<T, true>;
function useSearchParamsState (options: { name: string; default: string; }): SearchParamsState<string>;
function useSearchParamsState (options: { name: string }): SearchParamsState<string, true>;
function useSearchParamsState <T>(options: (
  & { name: string; default?: T; }
  & Partial<StringTransformers<T>>
)) {
  const {name, parse = identity<string>, stringify = identity<string>} = options;
  const [params, setParams] = useSearchParams();
  let value: T | string | undefined = params.get(name) ?? undefined;
  if (typeof value === 'string') value = parse(value);
  else if (typeof options.default !== 'undefined') value = options.default;

  const setter: ParsedSearchParamSetter<T> = (value, ...rest) => {
    const entries: Entry<string, string>[] = [];

    for (const entry of params.entries()) {
      if (entry[0] !== name) entries.push(entry);
    }

    const v = (stringify as StringTransformers<T>['stringify'])(value);
    entries.push([name, v]);
    setParams(entries, ...rest);
  };

  return [value, setter] as const;
}


// Usage:

// No args:
useSearchParamsState(); /* Error 2554
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

// No options:
useSearchParamsState({}); /* Error 2769
                     ~~ */

// No default results in possibly undefined value:
const [
  v1, // const v1: Maybe<string>
  s1, // const s1: ParsedSearchParamSetter<string>
] = useSearchParamsState({name: 'hello'});

// Including a default results in a definite value:
const [
  v2, // const v2: string
  s2, // const s2: ParsedSearchParamSetter<string>
] = useSearchParamsState({name: 'hello', default: 'world'});

// The type of the default value must match the return type of
// the provided transofrm fns (or be a string). The transform fns aren't provided,
// so a "number" is not valid here:
useSearchParamsState({name: 'hello', default: 2}); /* Error 2769
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~ */

// Missing "stringify" transform fn:
useSearchParamsState({
  name: 'hello',
  parse: (str: string) => str.length > 2, /* Error 2769
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
});

// Missing "parse" transform fn:
useSearchParamsState({
  name: 'hello',
  stringify: (bool: boolean) => '', /* Error 2769
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
});

// No default results in possibly undefined value:
const [
  v3, // const v3: Maybe<boolean>
  s3, // const s3: ParsedSearchParamSetter<boolean>
] = useSearchParamsState({
  name: 'hello',
  parse: (str: string) => str.length > 2,
  stringify: (bool: boolean) => '',
});

// Including a default results in a definite value:
const [
  v4, // const v4: boolean
  s4, // const s4: ParsedSearchParamSetter<boolean>
] = useSearchParamsState({
  name: 'hello',
  default: true,
  parse: (str: string) => str.length > 2,
  stringify: (bool: boolean) => '',
});
```

Comment: This is really amazing work! Thank you! I feel I need time to digest this now!

Comment: @JohnReilly Glad to hear that you found it helpful.